# No connection to Gdb Debugger (Error) in vs code

Tags: c++, gdb, vscode-debugger

The problem is that vs code doesn't let my compiled programs show output in terminal and says that "No connection to gdb  Debugger".
I have been using vs code for a while now, and this is the first time this happened.
The program builds successfully but debugger doesn't work.

I have been using vs code for a while and this happened for the first time. I didn't do anything that could cause such an issue and i am super confused about this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg0oI.png)

Here is my launch.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "E:/my64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Here is my task.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "E:/my64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "E:/my64/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

(I know these questions exist here but their solutions weren't proving to be beneficial so I need direct help.)

Comment: It says `Debug output may contain more information`. So what does the debug output say?

Comment: when this happens to me it's because I've forgotten to install gdb :). Seriously, though, it's worth the sanity check that `gdb --version` works on the command line. And then try running gdb manually on the command line before you conclude that the issue is in vs code.

Comment: Um so I reinstalled the debugger extension for C++ and it seems to be working fine now. The problem was probably within the extension. It just crashed for no reason

Answer (score 0):

Um so I reinstalled the debugger extension for C++ and it seems to be working fine now. The problem was probably within the extension. It just crashed for some reasons I don't know of.